# PaperJS random point

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I've got this code. What I want the code to do is to make the ball move and when the ball goes over a grey spot (holes) it goes back to the starting point. I've done that by creating a random place for the grey holes. I simply need to find a way to define the position of these holes even though they are randomized.

```
var startPoint = new Path.Circle(new Point(40, 40), 40);
startPoint.fillColor = "green";

//finishPoint 
var finishPoint = new Path.Circle(new Point(1300, 600), 40);
finishPoint.fillColor = "red";

var ball = new Path.Circle(new Point(40, 40), 20);
ball.fillColor = "black";

//holes 
var path = new Path(new Point(20, 20), new Point(20, 23));
path.style = {
    strokeColor: 'grey',
    strokeWidth: 70,
    strokeCap: 'round'
};

var holes = new Symbol(path);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var placement = view.size * Point.random();
    var placed = holes.place(placement);
}





var vector = new Point(0, 0);

function onFrame(event) {

    ball.position += vector / 100;
}
var moves = new Point(100, 1);

function onKeyDown(event) {
    if (event.key === "s") {
        vector.y += 10;
    }
    if (event.key === "d") {
        vector.x += 10;
    }
    if (event.key === "a") {
        vector.x -= 10;
    }
    if (event.key === "w") {
        vector.y -= 10;
    }

    var ballPlace = ball.position;
    if (ballPlace.isClose(finishPoint.position, 40) == true) {

        var text = new PointText(view.center);
        text.content = 'Congratulations';
        text.style = {
            fontFamily: 'Courier New',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: 100,
            fillColor: 'gold',
            justification: 'center'
        };
        ball.remove();
    }
if(ballPlace.isClose(placement.position, 40) == true) {
    ball = new Point(40, 40);
}
};
```

and I want the ball to go back to Point(40, 40) when it goes over a grey hole (var holes) but I can't get it to work. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why not store these points in an array?

Comment: yeah, I was thinking that.

Comment: but I know this is a very simple question but I'm really new to coding. How would I put it in an array?

Comment: `var arr = [];` to Init a new empty array.  Then `arr.push(obj);` to add objects to the array.  Might be worth reading up a bit more if you are still unsure.  Arrays are pretty basic concepts.

Comment: Thanks. I know the structure of arrays, I'm just a bit of a beginner :P

Comment: Everyone was at one stage.  Don't stop learning.

Comment: So I'm trying to figure out how to create these 10 random points by putting it in an array and I can't really get my head around how the array would look. any chance you can give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: no need, i think I have figured it out :) thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to test the ball's position against the holes to see if the ball goes back to the starting position. The simplest way I can think of to do this is to create a group of the holes then test the position of the ball against that group. In the following code the ball's position is simulated via the `onMouseMove` function and the holes are flashed red to indicate when the ball would be returned to the the starting position.

```
var holes = [];
var hole;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    hole = new Path.Circle(view.size * Point.random(), 10);
    hole.fillColor = 'grey';
    holes.push(hole);
}

holes = new Group(holes);

onMouseMove = function(e) {
    if (holes.hitTest(e.point)) {
        holes.fillColor = 'red';
    } else {
        holes.fillColor = 'grey';
    }
```

Here's an implementation: [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/hZAxb8IwEIX/yskLTkEWXUmZGDohIZWNMKTJpbYwd5HtBLUo/712Wgid6uXse+/8PvsqqDyjWIm3E4ZKi4WouE7ngvrSgWaLHtZwOOZTI24LatiBTB0T5WUeyws8pzqfZ3AtCOJK5qgSXmBXBq02xlUWZW/worz5QniCHRsKypVU81lmi3hFlk/DqjHWbtjGrDXMPhx+zh5Ur9rOa5m2aWhIWDfglPnquGtH2WcjM9OWO49b7hNW01EVDJPEO7Bp4MevtAl79EGiahNhdrdM4X/YHNY3tAHQevzH//iW4Ze9oPj97w7L05jpxepwHL4B). It should be straightforward to replaced `onMouseMove` with `onFrame`, move the ball as you currently do, and then test to see if it falls into a hole.

In order to test if the ball is over a hole you can remove on the `onMouseMove` function and replace it with:

```
onFrame = function(e) {
    ball.position += vector / 100;
    if (holes.hitTest(ball.position)) {
        // move the ball wherever you want to move it, position text,
        // etc. you might have to loop through the array to find which
        // hole was hit.
    }
}
```

Comment: well the array part of this is helpful but I want to test the balls position to the holes, not the mouse hovering over it. I've changed it a bit so I want a text to pop up when the ball's position is the same as the holes. when I do this it only works on one hole.

if (ballPlace.isClose(hole.position, 30) == true) {
        var text = new PointText(view.center);
        text.content = 'Game Over';....}
        
        ball.remove();
    }

Comment: @naomi I didn't realize that what I provided wasn't clear enough. I didn't want to duplicate all your code so I just did the essence of it. I'll add to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was clear enough :) I just didn't know how to apply the second part that you just showed me. Thank you so much! I need to read up a bit on hitTest, haven't come across that before.

Comment: Thanks. If this answers your question I would appreciate you accepting it. You may want to use `hitTest` or `isClose` depending on how you want the game to work. `hitTest` will return true when the center of the ball is within the circle of the hole. If that's not what you want then you may need to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

@Luke Park is right about using an array.

Trial each new point, by ensuring it is a distance from all other existing points. Example below (not scaled to view.size).

```
p = Point.random();
while ( isTooClose(p, points) ) {
    p = Point.random();
}
```

It's possible for this to loop infinitely, but if you're populating the area sparsely, there should be no problem.

isTooClose tests each point in array p, where distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy). If you have many points, you can optimise by avoiding sqrt(), by testing whether the raw dx and dy values are smaller than the test radius.

You can also use a similar function on each frame, to test for collision.

Comment: Did the OP ask about how to space out the positions of the holes?

Comment: @bmacnaughton I think so, but I might be mistaken ;o) "I simply need to find a way to define the position of these holes even though they are randomized" I interpreted as 'part 1' of the question, asking how to meaningfully position the holes. Part 2 was about detecting when a ball is over a hole. Both can be reduced to testing distances between points.

Comment: could be. I took it as  "holes are in random positions so how can I know where they are?" in order to detect when the ball is over them.